# Is it possible to access back end method in JSP?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, syntax, struts2, java-ee-6

I'm using Struts2 to build a web application and I have a back-end method in my `BaseAction` class, class which every other Action classes extends it, that looks like below:

```
public boolean isUserFullyLogged() {
    final Boolean isLogado = (Boolean) this.retrieveSessionAttribute(Constantes.LOGADO);
    return (isLogado != null) && isLogado.booleanValue();
}
```

I wish to use it in one of my JSPs to display or not some content, I've tried three different ways such as below:

- `<s:if test="#userFullyLogged">Content</s:if>`
- `<s:if test="%{#userFullyLogged}">Content</s:if>`
- `<s:if test="userFullyLogged">Content</s:if>`

But none of the above worked, the method is simply not called. Can someone tell me the correct syntax?

Comment: If method is `isUserFullyLogged` then `test="userFullyLogged"` and `test="isUserFullyLogged()"` should both work.

Answer (score 3):

No need to change the method name:

```xml
<s:if test="isUserFullyLogged()">Content</s:if>
```

Note that if you need to block the entire page, instead of a single functionality, you should do this kind of check inside an Interceptor, by applying the Interceptor Stack containing your custom `LoginInterceptor` to all the actions that need to be opened only by an authenticated user.

Comment: This expression _will_ work, but it's not "agnostic" in a Java sense... the JSP page shouldn't worry about the fact that the property is exposed using a method.  It should only be concerned that there is a property named "userFullyLogged".  It is preferable to directly use the property name `userFullyLogged` and let Struts worry about whether it is a method, a stack attribute, or some other level of exposure.

Answer (score 1):

The following form is preferable:

```
<s:if test="userFullyLogged">Content</s:if>
```

See [Struts2 if documentation](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/if.html): the test attribute is an expression.  Struts will resolve expression properties by calling your action class getters, assuming your getters are named according to JavaBean specification (which is the case, in your example).

Comment: Thanks for your time, but it's not working either. I don't know what's happenning, after I built a Interceptor I'm not able to access any of my back end methods anymore, not even the ones that used to work before building it, @GlennLane.

Comment: Just for a laugh, try changing it all to: `${userFullyLogged ? 'Content' : ''}` (don't use s:if)

Comment: That did not work on every pages. I think that has something to do with my *struts.xml*, because this is only working on actions that I explicitly declared a class.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi  If you don't explicitly declare an action class, how are you going to end up with an action that has the `isUserFullyLogged()` method?  Are you using `default-class-ref` in your struts.xml to specify your base class, or an extension of it?  That aside: the above _should_ work assuming your action class has a `public boolean isUserFullyLogged()` method.  No interceptors are required for the above to work.

Answer (score 0):

try to change that name to `getUserFullyLogged` and use

```
<s:if test="userFullyLogged">Content</s:if>
```

Actually calling a method

```
<s:if test="getUserFullyLogged()">Content</s:if>
```

Comment: The method name posted by the OP is correct, and shouldn't be changed.  Struts knows about the JavaBeans specification, and that a boolean getter should be prefixed with "is", not "get"

Comment: OGNL expressions follow the JavaBean specification when determining the getter method name for action properties.  When reflecting on the action methods to find a match for this property, OGNL will look for both `public ? getUserFullyLogged()` **and** `public boolean isUserFullyLogged()`.  Section 8.3.2 of [JavaBeans Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) outlines the design pattern for boolean properties: `isUserFullyLogged` is a valid getter name for boolean property `userFullyLogged`

Comment: @GlennLane JavaBean spec. is too old and didn't have updates for a decade. Struts2 and particular OGNL is tried to follow this spec., but with some minor modifications  that I won't discuss here.

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
<s:if test="isUserFullyLogged()"></s:if> or `<s:if test="isUserFullyLogged"></s:if>`
```

to call that method otherwise you have to set the value of this boolean result to a variable with proper getter-setter and use `<s:if test="%{#userFullyLogged}"></s:if>`

Thanks,
Amit Kumar Morea

Comment: No need to do this: simply using `userFullyLogged` will directly call the property getter in the action class, assuming the getter method is properly named as per JavaBean specification (which it is, in this case: `isUserFullyLogged`).